# Laravel: Use different env files for different domains for multi-tenant app

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I am trying to create a multi tenant application.

In other words I have a website, but it has multiple different versions of it with different branding, env variables and database connections. These sites are:

- sites1.test
- sites2.test

The easiest way I can think of doing this in Laravel is by having 2 different env files: `.env.site1` and `.env.site2`

This means for artisan commands I can simply do:

- `artisan migrate --env=site1` for site 1 commands
- `artisan migrate --env=site2` for site 2 commands

The issue I have is for HTTP requests. How can I configure laravel so that it:

- Uses `.env.site1` when on site1.test
- Uses `.env.site2` when on site.test

I also think there maybe some issues when caching the `.env` file.

Also, is there a potentially a better way to do multi-tenancy.

Comment: have you browsed this? https://laravel-tenancy.com/

Comment: This https://gist.github.com/msankhala/3c282abf546318a2662e may give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to have one staging env and one production. So create one .env.staging and one .env.production Then delete all lines in .env file except APP_ENV. Set this key to either staging or production:

```
APP_ENV=production
```

Then in your .env.production change any lines you want and then go to .env.staging and make different changes which fulfill your needs.

Comment: production and staging are just some examples. You can set them to anything you want. foe example .env.site1 and .env.site2 and then set the APP_ENV in .env file to one of these environments.

Comment: Also you can check this link out [link] (https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/configuration)